# Spatially merging 2 raster layers via "mosaic to new raster" causes a shift of the raster cells

Tags: arcmap

I intended to merge two raster datasets from the same source (one with values for north & south america) via the function "mosaic to new raster".

[image]

I used the following settings:

-> tif-file-extension; spatial reference according two the two ratser layers; 64 bit pixel type according to properties; band = 1

[image]

However, once the run was finished a very slight shift could be observed between the new raster and the two source rasters (see image below).

[image]

I tried with multpiple variations of the input settings but the slight shift generally remained and I have no further idea how to solve this.

Comment: Do they have same cell size?

Comment: Yes, the cell size is identical.